# Regular Expression | Apply Functional Programming to Convert Strings to URL Slugs

Tags: javascript, regex, functional-programming

**Question**

Fill in the urlSlug function so it converts a string title and returns the hyphenated version for the URL. You can use any of the methods covered in this section, and don't use replace. Here are the requirements:

The input is a string with spaces and title-cased words

The output is a string with the spaces between words replaced by a hyphen (-)

The output should be all lower-cased letters

The output should not have any spaces.

**My Solution**

```js
var globalTitle = " Winter Is  Coming";


function urlSlug(title) {
  let regex = /(?<!\s)\s(?!\s)/g
  
  let a = title
  .toLowerCase()
  .trim()
  .split(regex)
  .join('-')
  return a;
}


console.log(urlSlug(globalTitle))
```

**My Question**

I want to use positive and negative look aheads / look behinds to resolve this problem: my particular issue seems to be if the string has more than one space. What changes can be made to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use quantifier `+` which means one or more

```js
var globalTitle = " Winter Is  Coming";


function urlSlug(title) {
  let regex = /\s+/g
  
  let a = title
  .toLowerCase()
  .trim()
  .split(regex)
  .join('-')
  return a;
}


console.log(urlSlug(globalTitle))
```

Comment: were my look aheads and behinds doing anything?

Comment: Yes actually you don't need them anymore

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you need to split the string into an array.

```js
const slugify = (input = '') => 
  input
    .trim()
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
    .toLowerCase()
  ;


console.log(
  slugify(" Winter Is  Coming "),
);
```

---

PS: these operations are very error prone to be done manually, as there are tons of edge cases to be handled...

**I'd rather just install https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify which comes with a nice and configurable API**.

```js
console.log(
  slugify("   Winter is  Coming", { lower: true }),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slugify@1.4.0/slugify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be answered without using regex. With the filter method, there is no need to trim the method. Using a filter can be removed spaces from the list.
More information about filter can be found https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

```
  function urlSlug(urlTitle) {
   .split(" ")
   .filter(substr => substr !== "")
   .join("-")
   .toLowerCase();
  return urlTitle;
  }
```